# Roll a die 10 times. What is the probability that there is at least one number (1 through 6) that appears exactly 3 times in the sequence?

Tags: probability

My attempt is $\frac{6 * \binom{10}{5} * 5^7}{6^{10}}$

I haven't figure out what to do next. Should I use inclusion-exclusion method?

Comment: This is probably most easily solved as 100% minus the complement (that there are no numbers that appear exactly 3 times).

Comment: Every sequence is equally probable, so you can just count sequences of length $n$  on $6$ letters that have no $XXX$ blocks.  This can be done recursively.

Comment: @lulu though complicated by the possibility that one or two values appear $4$ or more times each

Comment: @Henry  It's not entirely straight forward, I agree.

Comment: My error, I read the question as asking for a block of three, as in $5552391...$.  That problem can be handled recursively.

Answer (score 2):

According to my interpretation, I thought you are interested in the probability that at least one of the 6 numbers appears exactly 3 times (in the sequence of 10 numbers.). If that is the case, here is how we can do it:

Let $A_i$ be the event that number $i$ appears exactly 3 times. We want to find $\Pr(A_1\cup A_2\cup A_3\cup A_4\cup A_5\cup A_6)$.

We can find that using inclusion-exclusion.
\begin{eqnarray*} 
&& \Pr(A_1\cup A_2\cup A_3\cup A_4\cup A_5\cup A_6)\\
&=& {6\choose 1}\Pr(A_1)-{6\choose 2}\Pr(A_1\cap A_2)+{6\choose 3}\Pr(A_1\cap A_2\cap A_3) \\ &=& {6\choose 1}{10\choose 3}\frac{5^7}{6^{10}}-{6\choose 2}{10\choose 3}{7\choose 3}\frac{4^4}{6^{10}}+{6\choose 3}{10\choose 3}{7\choose 3}{4\choose 3}\frac{3^1}{6^{10}} \\ &\approx & 0.9302722 - 0.2667276 + 0.01667048 \\ &\approx& 0.680215
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: +1. Your corrected final result of $0.680215$ is close to the simulation in R using `mean((replicate(10^5, sum(table(sample(1:6, 10, replace=TRUE))==3))) > 0)`

Comment: Thanks. I typed ${6\choose 2}$ rather than ${6\choose 3}$ into the console, that led to this approximation error. I have correct it now.

Comment: Thanks! That really helps me a lot.